# imported models couldn't collide each other

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Could you help me how can I make collide imported models?

I downloaded SUV model from here.
https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/models/SUV

and I uploaded this model to my world.sdf as below code.
you may find if you click the 'play button', two SUVs will be collided by gravity.

I could find these testing results.

1. Ignition gazebo's Box, Capsule and Sphere,, etc. can collide each other.
2. downloaded SUV model with Ignition gazebo's Box, Capsule and Sphere,, etc can collide each other.
3. downloaded SUV models couldn't collide each other.

```
    <model name='suv_110'>
        <static>0</static>
        <link name='chassis'>
          <collision name='collision'>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 -1.57079632679</pose>
            <geometry>
              <mesh>
                <scale>0.06 0.06 0.06</scale>
                <uri>https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/openrobotics/models/suv/2/files/meshes/suv.obj</uri>
              </mesh>
            </geometry>
          </collision>
          <visual name='visual'>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 -1.57079632679</pose>
            <geometry>
              <mesh>
                <scale>0.06 0.06 0.06</scale>
                <uri>https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/openrobotics/models/suv/2/files/meshes/suv.obj</uri>
              </mesh>
            </geometry>
          </visual>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
          <inertial>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
            <mass>1</mass>
            <inertia>
              <ixx>1</ixx>
              <ixy>0</ixy>
              <ixz>0</ixz>
              <iyy>1</iyy>
              <iyz>0</iyz>
              <izz>1</izz>
            </inertia>
          </inertial>
          <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
        </link>
        <pose>20 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>   </model>
```

```
<model name='suv_111'>
    <static>0</static>
    <link name='chassis'>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 -1.57079632679</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>0.06 0.06 0.06</scale>
            <uri>https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/openrobotics/models/suv/2/files/meshes/suv.obj</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 -1.57079632679</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>0.06 0.06 0.06</scale>
            <uri>https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/openrobotics/models/suv/2/files/meshes/suv.obj</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>1</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>1</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>1</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    </link>
    <pose>20 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  </model>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27844/imported-models-couldn%27t-collide-each-other/) by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) on 2022-02-20**:
[Testing environment]

- Linux Mint 20.2
- Installed Ignition version is Garden

**Comment by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) on 2022-02-20**:
https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu_src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Have a nice day! azeey.

Unfortunately, it's weird in my testing.
I wrote the sdf file based on this example code /usr/share/ignition/ignition-gazebo6/worlds/heightmap.sdf which has ground plane as below code.
this example code has already ground plane and if I just add SUVs, it shows that it is getting worse result. SUVs are through the ground plane without any collision. To avoid this, I had to use ground area 'https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Ground Plane'.

---

**[solved]**
That's a plugin reason.
by changing loading part of physics plugin from 'heightmap.sdf' to 'tunnel.sdf', it works fine.

```
<physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
</physics>
```

---

[my testing code]

bullet

```
<light type="directional" name="sun">
  <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
  <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
  <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
  <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
  <attenuation>
    <range>1000</range>
    <constant>0.9</constant>
    <linear>0.01</linear>
    <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
  </attenuation>
  <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
</light>

<model name="sphere_red">
  <pose>30 30 10 0 0 0</pose>
  <link name="sphere_link">
    <inertial>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>3</ixx>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyy>3</iyy>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
        <izz>3</izz>
      </inertia>
      <mass>3.0</mass>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="sphere_collision">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.5</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="sphere_visual">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.5</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <ambient>1 0 0 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
        <specular>1 0 0 1</specular>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>

<model name="sphere_green">
  <pose>30 -30 10 0 0 0</pose>
  <link name="sphere_link">
    <inertial>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>3</ixx>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyy>3</iyy>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
        <izz>3</izz>
      </inertia>
      <mass>3.0</mass>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="sphere_collision">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.5</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="sphere_visual">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.5</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <ambient>0 1 0 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>0 1 0 1</diffuse>
        <specular>0 1 0 1</specular>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>

<model name="sphere_blue">
  <pose>-30 30 10 0 0 0</pose>
  <link name="sphere_link">
    <inertial>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>3</ixx>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyy>3</iyy>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
        <izz>3</izz>
      </inertia>
      <mass>3.0</mass>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="sphere_collision">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.5</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="sphere_visual">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.5</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <ambient>0 0 1 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>0 0 1 1</diffuse>
        <specular>0 0 1 1</specular>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>

<model name="sphere_yellow">
  <pose>-30 -30 20 0 0 0</pose>
  <link name="sphere_link">
    <inertial>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>3</ixx>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyy>3</iyy>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
        <izz>3</izz>
      </inertia>
      <mass>3.0</mass>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="sphere_collision">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.5</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="sphere_visual">
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.5</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <ambient>1 1 0 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>1 1 0 1</diffuse>
        <specular>1 1 0 1</specular>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>

<include>
  <uri>
    https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/chapulina/models/Heightmap Bowl
  </uri>
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) with karma: 5 on 2022-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0